# polymer 1.0 select element in dom-if template

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am having what seems to be a common issue with Polymer 1.0: accessing nodes inside a dom-if template, but none of the proposed solutions seem to work in my case (?!)..

Here is a simple example:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-test">
  <template>
    <div>
      <template is="dom-if" if="{{show}}" id="tplId">
        <p id="message">hello</p>
      </template>
    </div>
    <a on-tap="tapEvent">click me!</a>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-test',
        show: false,
        ready: function() {
        },
        tapEvent: function() {
          // show the template
          this.show = true;

          // How may I access #message since the template is inhert ?

          // this finds the template by id
          console.log(Polymer.dom(tplId));

          // this won't find the #message element inside it
          console.log(Polymer.dom(tplId).querySelector('#message'))

          // this neither
          console.log(Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#message'))

          // this neither
          console.log(Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('#message'))

          // this neither .. Should I even be using this.shadowRoot in 1.0?
          console.log(Polymer.dom(this.shadowRoot).querySelector('#message'))

          // this neither
          console.log(this.$$('#message'))

          // this cannot work because #message is not a statically created DOM element
          console.log(this.$.message)

        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I'm new to Polymer, and I feel the solution might be right under my nose..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this

```
     // this neither
      console.log(this.$$('#message'))
```

doesn't work then you probably try to query the element while it doesn't exist. When `show` is `false` the `<p id="message">` element doesn't exist at all. If you need this then bind to `hidden` instead of using `dom-if`

```
<p id="message" hidden$="{{show}}">hello</p>
```

then

```
console.log(this.$.message);
```

will work as well.